# Entity Framework edit data in grid bound to Entity which uses joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which binds to a database through Entities (I am using a Database First approach).

I want to display data in a grid (and update this information before posting back to the database) for an Entity which contains Navigation Properties (i.e. Joins).

The context is that there are Permissions in the application; these permissions are separated into relevant sections and every user either has this permission or does not.

[image: The relationships between the tables]

*The relationships between the tables*

In the dialog, there are two grids; one to show the sections available and another to show the permissions within that section and whether the user has that permission enabled; the bottom grid dynamically populates based on the row selected in the top grid.

The DataGridView has `AutoGenerateColumns = false` and this cannot change (this is because it's a custom `DataGridView` to which you add columns yourself due to additional properties being required); additionally, the `DataPropertyName` is set to that of the column I want to display from the appropriate table.

The two approaches I have explored so far are as follows:

1. Load entire `USER_PERMISSIONS` entity and bind the DataGridView:

   ```
   PermissionsSectionContext.PERMISSIONS_SECTION
       .Load();

   PermissionsValues.USER_PERMISSIONS
       .Where(x => x.USER_ID == 5)
       .Load();

   SectionsGrid.DataSource = 
       new BindingSource(
           PermissionsSectionContext
           .PERMISSIONS_SECTION.Local.ToBindingList(), null);

   ValuesGrid.DataSource =
       new BindingSource(
           PermissionsValues
           .USER_PERMISSIONS.Local
       .Where(x => x.PERMISSIONS_NAME.PERMSECTION_ID == 1), null);
   ```

**Problem**: This loads the items fine and I can also edit the permissions values and post this back to the database however the Permissions names (i.e. `x.PERMISSIONS_NAME.FRIENDLY_NAME`) do not show in the grid:

[image: The Permissions descriptions (i.e. x.PERMISSIONS_NAME.FRIENDLY_NAME) is blank]

The `DataPropertyName` values of the columns in the bottom grid are 'FRIENDLY_NAME' and 'VALUE'.

2. Creating Anonymous types and then setting the 'Column names' using these anonymous types:

   ```
   PermissionsSectionContext.PERMISSIONS_SECTION
       .Load();

   PermissionsValues.USER_PERMISSIONS
       .Where(x => x.USER_ID == 5)
       .Load();

   SectionsGrid.DataSource = 
       new BindingSource(
           PermissionsSectionContext
           .PERMISSIONS_SECTION.Local.ToBindingList(), null);

   ValuesGrid.DataSource =
       new BindingSource(
           PermissionsValues
           .USER_PERMISSIONS.Local
       .Where(x => x.PERMISSIONS_NAME.PERMSECTION_ID == 1), null)
       .Select(x => new {
       FRIENDLY_NAME = x.PERMISSIONS_NAME.FRIENDLY_NAME,
       VALUE = x.VALUE});
   ```

**Problem**: All the values show exactly as I want in the grids, including the Permission Name; however, you cannot edit the 'Value' column. Debugging this reveals that when the anonymous type is bound to the `DataGridView`, it is setting the `ReadOnly` property to `true`; this column still needs to be editable and for `SaveChanges()` to post these changes back, which does work for option (1).

Comment: So use named types (aka view model or DTO).

Comment: I tried creating a class which contained only the fields that I wanted and whilst this worked in terms of bringing back the data, it still resulted in the joined table (aka PERMISSIONS_NAME) not returning the FRIENDLY_NAME; also, as it involved calling `ToList()`, it only allowed for one-way data transfer and did not communicate the changes back to the Database as it was not adding changes into `DbContext.ChangeTracker`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold)'s initial response about using named types (many thanks for the pointer!) I did a bit of reading around and I have managed to get this working as I require.

The first thing I did was create a class which contained only the fields that I was going to use as part of the data operations:

```
private class UserPermissionsValue
{
    public int? PERMISSION_ID { get; set; }
    public int? PERMSECTION_ID { get; set; }
    public string FRIENDLY_NAME { get; set; }
    public int? VALUE { get; set; }
}
```

As I needed to store all of the permissions which were applicable against the user and then only show, in the bottom grid, those which were relevant to the selected row in the top grid, I kept all of the permissions against the user in a `List<UserPermissionsValue>`:

```
private List<UserPermissionsValue> UserPermissionsList = new List<UserPermissionsValue>();
```

I could then get the records that I needed for this list using projection on the base entities:

```
UserPermissionsList = ValuesGrid.DbContext.USER_PERMISSIONS.Local
    .Select(x => new UserPermissionsValue { 
        PERMISSION_ID = x.PERMISSION_ID,
        PERMSECTION_ID = x.PERMISSIONS_NAME.PERMSECTION_ID,
        FRIENDLY_NAME = x.PERMISSIONS_NAME.FRIENDLY_NAME,
        VALUE = x.VALUE
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Using the existing `_RowEnter` event I had set up, I could simply select the permissions from the section I needed and then bind this to the grid:

```
int PermissionsSection = ((DataEntity.PERMISSIONS_SECTION)ValuesGrid
    .Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).PERMSECTION_ID;

ValuesGrid.DataSource = UserPermissionsList
    .Where(x => x.PERMSECTION_ID == PermSectionID)
    .ToList();
```

This had the benefit of the modified values being maintained and 'remembered' when changing options in the top grid, as the value and subsequent changes were bound to `UserPermissionsList`.

Finally, when confirming the dialog, the actual entities were brought in and their values were updated to what they had been set to in the dialog itself; I decided it would be less of a load to bring back all entities in a single request and then iterate through the collection of entities locally, rather than get the records from the DB one-by-one and update them that way:

```
var PermissionsCommitList = ValuesGrid.DbContext
    .USER_PERMISSIONS.Local;

foreach (DataEntity.USER_PERMISSIONS permission in PermissionsCommitList)
    {
        UserPermissionsValue ValueToCommit = UserPermissionsList
        .Where(x => x.PERMISSION_ID == permission.PERMISSION_ID)
        .First();

        permission.VALUE = ValueToCommit.VALUE;
    }
dtgPermissionsSettings.pFormGrid.DataEntityProvider.SaveChanges();
```